# unexpected regex results in html

Tags: html, regex

try to extract with regex in the following but returns four values :

```
<a id="ucManageTaxFilesGridControl_gridAccountHistory_lnkHistoryTaxFileName_3" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ucManageTaxFilesGridControl$gridAccountHistory$ctl05$lnkHistoryTaxFileName&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:0.8em;font-weight:bold;">TaxFile1</a>

              </td><td>                                                
                <span id="ucManageTaxFilesGridControl_gridAccountHistory_lblHistoryStatus_3" style="color:Black;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:0.8em;">Opened</span>
```

this is the regular expression that I use :

```
<a(?:[^>]id\=\"ucManageTaxFilesGridControl_gridAccountHistory_lnkHistoryTaxFileName.*?\".*?doPostBack\(&#39;(.*?)\&\#39[^>]*)?>(.*?)<\/a>(.*?(\n))+.*<span.*?id=\"ucManageTaxFilesGridControl_gridAccountHistory_lblHistoryStatus_.*\">Opened<\/span>
```

the following result is obained:

1. ucManageTaxFilesGridControl$gridAccountHistory$ctl02$lnkHistoryTaxFileName
2. TaxFile1
3. ¬
4. ¬

Please How can I get this expected result ?

1. ucManageTaxFilesGridControl$gridAccountHistory$ctl02$lnkHistoryTaxFileName
2. TaxFile1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got the answer :<a(?:[^>]id\=\"ucManageTaxFilesGridControl_gridAccountHistory_lnkHistoryTaxFileName.*?\".*?doPostBack\(&#39;(.*?)\&\#39[^>]*)?>(.*?)<\/a>\n.*?+\n.*?<\/td><td>.*\n.*?<span\sid\=\"ucManageTaxFilesGridControl_gridAccountHistory_lblHistoryStatus.*?\".*?>Opened<\/span>

Comment: Howcome you don't represent those long strings as `\w+`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to match `ucManageTaxFilesGridControl$gridAccountHistory$ctl02$lnkHistoryTaxFileName` or `TaxFile1` in the string provided and quoted below:

> ```
>     </td><td>                                                
>         <span id="ucManageTaxFilesGridControl_gridAccountHistory_lblHistoryStatus_3" style="color:Black;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:0.8em;">Opened</span>
> ```

Comment: Sorry novice in stackoverflow . I review my question and I correct the html code